# Как сделать связь между двумя моделями?

Tags: model, миграция, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте.

У меня возникла необходимость сделать связь в Ruby on Rails, где одна модель ссылается на другую (которая является неким подобием свитча): в базах данных это выглядит так:
http://goo.gl/w5sKN0

Я так полагаю, что это что-то вроде полиморфной связи, но немного другое. 
Прошу пнуть меня в правильном направлении.

**UPDATE** Спасибо Чад за свое решение.Мое решение данной задачи выглядит так:

**Миграция**

```
#db/schema.rb
  create_table "switchs", force: true do |t|
    #t.references :switch, polymorphic: true - в миграции
    #t.references :item - в миграции
    t.integer  "switch_id"
    t.string   "switch_type"
    t.integer  "item_id"
  end

  create_table "options", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    ...
  end
  create_table "items", force: true do |t|
     t.string  "name"
     ...
  end
```

Соответственно сама модель Switch сразу будет иметь 2а типа связи и ***polymorphic:*** и ***has_many :through***

```
#app/models/switch.rb
  class Switch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :switch, polymorphic: true
    ...
  end
```

Модель item ссылается на модель через ***source_type:*** и id в указанной модели ***source:"switch"***

```
#app/models/item.rb
  class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :switchs
    has_many :options, through: :switchs, source_type: "Option", source:"switch"
    has_many :photos, through: :switchs, source_type: "Photo", source:"switch"
    ...
  end
#app/models/option.rb
  class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items, through: :switchs
    has_many :switchs, as: :switch
    ...
  end
```

Ну и принцип работы по всем традициям rails =)

```
>item = Item.create(name: "Street")
>option = Option.create(title: "Manhattan")
>item.options.push option
```

Comment: @eviper74, я думаю имеет смысл оформить это в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, Single Table Interface...

Comment: Я смотрел STI, но немного не понял принцип работы.

Comment: http://rubydev.ru/2011/07/rdr3t-single-table-inheritance-rails/

Comment: Просто, я так понимаю, чтобы динамически добавлять элементы в базу данных, мне потребуется делать свои sql-запросы, если это будет STI решение, т.е. писать методы и т.д. (если я правильно понял). Решение вроде бы тоже имеет место быть, но решение моей проблемы гораздо проще в том коде, что я написал выше=)

Comment: @eviper74, отличное решение, забыл про полиморф, спасибо.Для STI не надо писать свои запросы. Общая идея там такая что в одной таблице все поля всех хранящихся там классов, и поле type которое указывает какой класс у текущего объекта.

Answer (score 0):

Если топорно, то можно сделать такое решение (потом можете придумать, как сделать совсем красиво, главное поделитесь, как :-) )

```
class PolyMorph < ActiveRecord::Base

def linked_object
  #тут главное чтобы был контроль на то что попадает в eval
  eval(self.model).find(self.id_in_model)
end

def linked_object=value
  value.save!
  self.id_in_model = value.id
  self.model = value.class.to_s
end

end
```

Как разобрался сам автор вопроса, стандартная парадигма актив рекорда для этого - это
[полиморфизм](http://rusrails.ru/active-record-associations#polymorphic-associations).